# How do you say "stay oriented" in Esperanto?

Tags: single-word-requests

I watched a video of a woman speaking about a tribe in Australia who use east, west, north and south instead of right and left.

She said that they "stay oriented really well". How can I express this in Esperanto? I am guessing I will have to use some other words, like "they know where they're going" or "they know their directions".

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RKK7wGAYP6k

Answer (score 4):

The complete sentence in that video is this:

> In fact, people who speak languages like this stay oriented really
>   well.

I would translate it like this:

*Fakte, homoj, kiuj parolas tiajn lingvojn konservas tre bone la/sian orientiĝon*.

Or like this:

*Fakte, homoj, kiuj parolas tiajn lingvojn konservas tre bone la kapablon sin orienti*.

Or simply:

*Fakte, homoj, kiuj parolas tiajn lingvojn sin orientas tre bone*.

Answer (score 2):

*Orientiĝi* / *sin orienti*: [PIV](http://vortaro.net/#sin%20orienti), [ReVo](http://reta-vortaro.de/revo/art/orient.html#orient.0igxi).

For the particular phrase you're looking for, I'd say something like *resti (ĝuste) orientiĝinta*.

Answer (score 1):

Given *sin orienti*, the most concise way to express the idea is *resti orientitaj*. Since they're orienting themselves, you don't need the "iĝ". Since the original sense is that they remain in this oriented state (and not that they constantly re-orient themselves), the best verb is *resti.*